# JSON.parse performs unwanted data sorting

Tags: json, sorting, select

I have this json object ( result ) as returned from an ajax call :

```
{
    "2": "Buenos Aires",
    "3": "Catamara",
    "16": "Chaco",
    "17": "Chubut",
    "1": "Ciudad Aut\u00f3noma de Buenos Aires",
    "4": "C\u00f3rdoba",
    "5": "Corrientes",
    "6": "Entre R\u00edos",
    "18": "Formosa",
    "7": "Jujuy",
    "21": "La Pampa",
    "9": "La Rioja",
    "8": "Mendoza",
    "19": "Misiones",
    "20": "Neuqu\u00e9n",
    "22": "R\u00edo Negro",
    "10": "Salta",
    "11": "San Juan",
    "12": "San Luis",
    "23": "Santa Cruz",
    "13": "Santa Fe",
    "14": "Santiago del Estero",
    "24": "Tierra del Fuego",
    "15": "Tucum\u00e1n"
}
```

As you can see, it is sorted by the name of the provinces.

The issue comes when a define

```
var list = JSON.parse( result )
```

in order to populate a select tag.

But list becomes this :

{ 1: "Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires", 2: "Buenos Aires", 3: "Catamara", 4: "Córdoba", 5: "Corrientes", 6: "Entre Ríos", 7: "Jujuy", 8: "Mendoza", 9: "La Rioja", 10: "Salta" ... and so on ...

"list" now contains the data sorted by the code ... Is there a way to populate the select tag with the information exactly as it was receive from the ajax call ?

Comment: Objects are unordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When object properties that represent integer numbers are iterated, they are returned in numerical order. This iteration order has not always been defined, but since ES6 it has been defined like that.

If you want to maintain a certain order, you need to store the information in an array, not in a plain object.

Here is ES6 code to convert your object to an array, and have it sorted by the city name, although it would be better if your server returned it in that way:

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj)
                .map ( key => [key, obj[key]] )
                .sort ( (a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]) );
```

See it run in this snippet:

```js
var json = `{
    "2": "Buenos Aires",
    "3": "Catamara",
    "16": "Chaco",
    "17": "Chubut",
    "1": "Ciudad Aut\u00f3noma de Buenos Aires",
    "4": "C\u00f3rdoba",
    "5": "Corrientes",
    "6": "Entre R\u00edos",
    "18": "Formosa",
    "7": "Jujuy",
    "21": "La Pampa",
    "9": "La Rioja",
    "8": "Mendoza",
    "19": "Misiones",
    "20": "Neuqu\u00e9n",
    "22": "R\u00edo Negro",
    "10": "Salta",
    "11": "San Juan",
    "12": "San Luis",
    "23": "Santa Cruz",
    "13": "Santa Fe",
    "14": "Santiago del Estero",
    "24": "Tierra del Fuego",
    "15": "Tucum\u00e1n"
}`;

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var arr = Object.keys(obj)
                .map ( key => [key, obj[key]] )
                .sort ( (a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]) );

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This is what I need.  Regards.

Comment: This code is not working for this code,  var json = '{"Fabric":{"1199":{"title":"Fabric"},"1164":{"title":"Ultimate Leather"}}}';   I need 1199 first then 1164. But using this code i getting same result in the ascending order , 1164 first and then 1199

Comment: Is there any solution then? Because i am really stuck and looking for this since last week.

Comment: I suggest asking a new question, because it is not clear where the keys could be in your nested structure, and what determines that they should be taken into account for sorting, and what happens when there are multiple such keys in the same top level object... etc. All that should be clearly explained and specified in a new question.

Comment: This is the que what i asked, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947795/json-parse-changes-element-order-if-the-key-is-a-numerical-string please check

Comment: That question looks at the order in an object. As I stated in my answer here, that order is fixed by EcmaScript rules. If you need order, you should use an array, not a plain object, and then the script in my answer can be used.